# Most recent timestamp for each person

Tags: sql

I have a table with people and timestamps.  Each person has multiple timestamps

```
SELECT person, time FROM table;

A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2
B 3
```

I would like to get the most recent timestamp for each person

```
SELECT ????

  A 2
  B 3
```

Comment: Which database system, and which version? - makes quite a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` will do the trick :

```
SELECT person, MAX(time)
FROM table
GROUP BY person
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle:

```
 SELECT person, MAX(time)
 FROM table
 GROUP BY person
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT person, MAX(time) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY person
```